# how can I input information data when app is in first startup?

Tags: android

I want input data in internal storage of my app when my app installed in new device & never change(delete & update &insert). my information is heavy & if I input my information in oncreate() every time that user open my app information will be make again & I don't like it.how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that is a `Broadcastreceiver` and register it in your manifest to receiver `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL` actions. It will be called only when the application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assets folder and put your heavy data there. It will be installed with application package. You can find information about that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).